# typescript не ругается на переданные аргументы в компоненте с дифисом? почему так и можно ли это как то исправить?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const D: FC<{ name?: string }> = () => {
   return <div></div>;
};

//типо все окей
<D xxx-xxx="1" />;
```

Comment: А почему он должен ругаться?

Comment: @AlexeyTen потому что такого аргумента не указано в интерфейсе.

Comment: А TS-у это неважно. Его интересуют только типы которые *указаны* в интерфейсе. Лишние свойства ему не мешают (за исключением литеральных объектов) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out

Comment: @AlexeyTen как это не мешают, туда же нельзя нечего лишнего передать кроме как что то с дефисом

Comment: У вас же пропсы не передаются, на что должен ругаться TS. Можно решить проблему если передать пропсы

Comment: @Randall простой ворпос почему он дапускает передачу xxx-xxx но не ххх

Comment: Подозреваю, что ради data- и aria-атрибутов старались. Возможно, им стоит что-то обновить...

Comment: @Qwertiy да уже успел где то прочитать что типо так и должно быть...., не совсем, делал нечто похожое на tailwind (только на уровне компонентов) и пропсы boolean типо text-align-center, в итоге решил эту проблему на этапе кампиляции обычной проверкой на наличие не сушествуюших имен и выброса ошибки... такое се решение но все же.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript не ругается на ваше "xxx-xxx", тк в React допускаются компоненты с дефисами. Но, такие атрибуты не могут быть напрямую указаны в типе свойств компонента, тк дефис является недопустимым символом в идентификаторах ts.

Чтобы исправить подобное поведение, можно написать интерфейс для свойств компонента.

```typescript
interface MyProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  'xxx-xxx'?: string;
}
```

Далее используем MyProps в роли типа свойств компонента:

```typescript
const D: FC<MyProps > = ...
```

Теперь тс будет проверять тип передаваемых свойств, в тч ваш "xxx-xxx". Если "xxx-xxx" не будет в свойствах компонента, он примет значение undefined

Comment: `Typescript не ругается на ваше "xxx-xxx", тк в React допускаются компоненты с дефисами` вот эту часть можно чуток детальнее, я не уловил почему он допускает аргумент каторого нету в интерфейсе.

Comment: Ну как, тс допускает, передачу аргументов, которых нету в интерфейсе, тк он основан на структурной типизации. Это означает, что типы сравниваются на основе их структуры, а не имени или места объявления. Таким образом, ваше "xxx-xxx" имеет идентичную структуру с любым другим наименованием свойства, например "xxxaaa".

Наглядный пример: 
Имеет интерфейс User, в котором объявлены свойства "email": string, и "age": number.
`const john: User = {email:"johndoe@gmail.com", age: 32, pets: ["cat"]}`

Comment: john не является ошибкой, тк он хоть и имеет дополнительное свойство pets, он всё ещё имеет такую же структуру, как и у интерфейса User. 

Но это я что то увлёкся в основы. Надеюсь стало хоть каплю понятнее ^_^

Comment: так же не сработает:

`interface IZ {
  name: string;
}

const x: IZ = {
  name: 'dasd',
  sur: '222',
};`

будет ошибка.

суть н в каличестве аргументов, ведь один же аргумент и это обект, почему с `IZ` все четко, а вот с `props` нет, также попытка передать `abc` как аргумент будет ошибка а вот `abc-abc` нет.

Comment: если включить стрикт мод - да. Но без него, конструкция описанная выше рабочая. В вашем вопросе, вероятно, выключен стрикт мод, из за чего тс считает это допустимым свойством и пропускает

Comment: `"strict": true,` в конфиге)